# Why was this edit rejected? How is the reviewer's edit better?

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits, specific-edit, reject-reasons

Why was [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/31937757) rejected?

The reviewer's action was "Reject and Edit". I don't know how [that edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72484763/2) is better than mine and why mine was rejected.

The additional text provided by the system as explanation for "Reject and Edit" says:

> This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed.

I think I corrected the critical issues with the post and made the post clearer without changing the OP's intentions.

Now, I also don't see how the other edit corrects the critical issues with the post.

Comment: Possibly due to [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) Also, how do you know that by "me" they mean the bot, and not the OP's personal account?

Comment: @Ivar That seems likely enough to me.

Comment: @Ivar, I know that tags shouldn't be included in titles and had it in mind while editing too, but https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/356861/1056862. I feel it's not bad either. It does help, and the question's answer probably varies in discord.py and discord.js. But how can the edit be rejected *just* because of that?

Comment: @Ivar, it's 99% the bot and not the OP's Discord account.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder Taking a closer look at the question and your edit, I think I shouldn't have rejected it. Your edit looks pretty good. I'm sorry.

Comment: I was unsatisfied with the overall writing of the comment even after those edits, but they were enough for me to understand the question finally (I am the one who originally commented). I went ahead and re-edited to make the question as clear as possible.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In full honesty, I shouldn't have rejected your edit. I didn't look thoroughly at the edit nor the original question, but in the side-by-side markdown view, it looked to me like the edit changed but didn't really improve the post, so I rejected it and made a few edits myself, which I now realize were the worse (and fewer) than yours. I had encounterd many very poor edits this morning and assumed that yours was one of them. I'm very sorry about that.

I re-applied your edit. I'm sorry for the undeserved bad mark on your edit record and your loss of potential rep. Hopefully you'll suggest more good edits that diminish those :)

As for the "This edit did not correct critical issues" message - that's system-generated and meaningless in this case.

At very least, you've helped me understand that though there are many posts in the suggested edits queue, paying due attention to each individual one is worth it.

Comment: I was trying to get the raw source of the suggested edit. Thanks for editing it :D